Ruby ハッシュオブジェクトを新しい配列に格納したときの挙動について
最近Rubyの学習を始めた初学者です。
Rubyの参考書の練習問題にて不明な点がありまして、
その練習問題の内容ですが

menu = {"コーヒー" => 300, "カフェラテ" => 400}から全キーを持つ配列(["コーヒー","カフェラテ"])を作ってください

という内容でその解答が
menu = {"コーヒー" => 300, "カフェラテ" => 400}
keys = []
menu.each do |key,value|
     keys.push(key)
end

p keys  # -> ["コーヒー","カフェラテ"]

となります。
そこで、ブロック変数|key,value|を|key|だけにして実行してみた結果
menu = {"コーヒー" => 300, "カフェラテ" => 400}
keys = []
menu.each do |key|
     keys.push(key)
end

p keys  # -> [["コーヒー",300],["カフェラテ",400]]

と、このような実行結果になりました。
質問1
ブロック変数|key,value|を定義した結果
空の配列keysに変数menuのkey"コーヒー"と"カフェラテ"だけが格納される理由
質問2
ブロック変数|key|と定義した結果
[["コーヒー",300],["カフェラテ",400]]と二次元配列のようになる理由
以上の二点について初学者に分かりやすくご教授いただければ幸いです。
長文失礼いたしました。

ハッシュに対して each するときは質問文にあるような挙動になります。ドキュメント: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Hash/i/each.html
ハッシュ menu に対して each するとき、menu.each { |k, v| ... } と引数をふたつ持つブロックを渡すと、ハッシュのキーと値を分割してそれぞれ k と v に入れた上でブロックの評価をします。一方 menu.each { |e| ... } のように引数をひとつ持つブロックを渡すと、ハッシュのキーと値を配列にしたもの [k, v] が e に入った上でブロックが評価されます。したがって質問文に書かれている実行結果が生まれます。
なお、ご質問と直接は関係ありませんが、ハッシュのキーを取り出すのみであれば Hash#keys メソッドを使って menu.keys と書けばそれだけでキーのみを取り出せます。
